# Property for changing an object-attribute in an object

Tags: python, class, properties

I need to call a method, when a attribute of an object within an object is changed. So I went with properties but without success.

I used properties to check if the object within the object is changing. But that only calls the setter if I assign a new or existing object of that type and not when I change attribute within.

```
class Position:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = 0
        self.y = 0

class Player:
    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.__position = Position()
        self.__position.x = x
        self.__position.y = y

    @property
    def position(self):
        return self.__position

    @position.setter
    def position(self, value):
        print('Position changed')
        self.__position = value

player = Player(5, 10)
player.position = Position() # Setter gets called
player.position.x = 10 # Setter doesn't get called
```

Currently that example prints "Position changed" once in line `player.position = Position()`. But I need to call the setter, when X or Y is changed.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: When you do player.position.x you are not setting player.position, you are just changing values in the position object. player.position is still the same Position instance it was. player.position = Position(10,10) would probably work as expected.

Comment: @MatthewPage and there is no way to check if X or Y is changed? Without assigning a new Position?

Comment: sorry, not that far into Python yet, but in theory yes there is. If Player extended the Position class would the Position class know about it's parent, again I'm not sure about Python OO. The Position class needs to say 'Tell what ever created me that I've changed' , usually by calling message method in the parent..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **Question**:  I need to call the setter, when X or Y is changed.

If you want to get informed, if `x` or `y` get changed, use `x.setter` and `y.setter`.

For example:

```
@x.setter
def x(self, value):
    print('Position X changed')
    self.__position.x = value
```

> **Usage**:

```
player.x = 10
```